# Xampp, Apache and Java

Tags: javascript, apache, xampp, dreamweaver

I have a MacBook Pro running Yosemite.  I have loaded xampp, latest version of Java and Dreamweaver cs6.   I cannot get the localhost to display the Java code.  How can I get My local host to display the Java code in my website?

Comment: Are you trying to compile JSP files?

Comment: No I  just trying to display a web page on my local host.

Comment: Where did you put the web page file on the disk?

Comment: In the htdoc folder under xampp

Comment: what url are you visiting in the browser to see the page?

Comment: http://localhost/compassyachtcharters/wwwroot/index.php

Comment: http://localhost/compassyachtcharters/wwwroot/index.php

Comment: Check the port that XAMP is running apache on.  By default its 8080 so you'll need to do something like: http://localhost:8080/compassyachtcharters/wwwroot/index.php

Comment: Ok I tried that.  The browser can't open anything using the 8080.  Apache is listening on port 80 according to Xampp apache config window

Comment: BTW the page displays everything but the java content using the url I posted.

Comment: ok. Can you post how the java code is written?